# if I write code es6, what would be better? (let,const)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, let

If I write ECMAScript 6 code, what will be better: to use only let and const or var too? I know the difference between them, but I want to know can I not use var at all? What is the best practice?
I wanted to ask about Code Style

Comment: There's a good topic about this on another SE site http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/274342/is-there-any-reason-to-use-the-var-keyword-in-es6

Comment: The general consensus for the JS devs I know is "Use `const` until you can't, then use `let`"

Comment: Short and sweet - In ES6, `var` is the least specific of the three. It's usually best to use `const` when you know you don't want to change the value and use `let` in any other case.

Comment: relevant: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-const

Answer (score 3):

[Nice write-up](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-es6-var-let-or-const-ba58b8dcde75) by Eric Elliot on this topic: (Emphasis mine)

> [...] I favor `const` over `let` in ES6. In JavaScript, `const` means that the identifier can’t be reassigned. (Not to be confused with immutable values. Unlike true immutable datatypes such as those produced by Immutable.js and Mori, a `const` object can have properties mutated.)
>
> If I don’t need to reassign, **`const` is my default choice** over `let` because I want the usage to be as clear as possible in the code.
>
> I use `let` when I need to reassign a variable. Because I use one variable to represent one thing, **the use case for `let` tends to be for loops** or mathematical algorithms.
>
> I **don’t use `var` in ES6**. There is value in block scope for loops, but I can’t think of a situation where I’d prefer `var` over `let`.